# On which set (train/val/test) do people calculate F1 score, precision and recall?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall, scoring-rules, f1

This may be a stupid question, but when I was looking at the definition of precision/recall etc. it was not mentioned anywhere which set (training/validation/test) this metric should be calculated against.

https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/precision-and-recall

Is this metric used to select the best model or evaluate the final model?

Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: The score on training data is the least important. After that, you would calculate it on a validation set to tune hyperparameters and then on a final test set to estimate model performance. However, keep in mind that $F_1$, like accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity, is an improper scoring rule that does not [consider the predicted probabilities](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/).

Comment: Dave said it well, and it deserves to be repeated: the test set is never for model selection. Don't look at it until you've done all the tuning and engineering you want, and you're done re-trianing/tweaking your model. It is your proxy for the real world, and in the real world you don't get do-overs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding this distinction is important in ML.

Usually, you use precision, recall, and F1 to *evaluate the (generalization) performance of your model*.

Therefore, you compute these on the *test set*.

Separately from this, you also need to select a single metric to optimize your model hyperparameters during training and validation, eg, via (inner) cross-validation. Often this is accuracy or ROC AUC but it could be anything. This is where the art comes in. You may stick to a default metric to begin with.